# Docker container name conflict conflict, but that container doesn't exist

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm trying to run a container with a name I used before, but it says `Conflict. The name "/szeremi-blog" is already in use by container e3424e6548302125f51ace8b6777190f02bb9b32606dba4471ecc64796010413. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..` even though that container doesn't exist, not even stopped!

I'm using Docker version 1.10.3

Oh by the way I did have an issue regarding the disk space filling up completely. Maybe some needed data failed to write that is causing this problem?

```
core@www ~/szeremi-nginx $ /usr/bin/docker run --rm --name szeremi-blog     -e VIRTUAL_HOST=blog.szeremi.org     -v /mnt/szeremi-blog/sites:/var/www/html/sites     -v /mnt/szeremi-blog/uploads:/var/www/uploads     --link mysql     ${CONTAINER_NAME}:8.0
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "/szeremi-blog" is already in use by container e3424e6548302125f51ace8b6777190f02bb9b32606dba4471ecc64796010413. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..
core@www ~/szeremi-nginx $ docker rm e3424e6548302125f51ace8b6777190f02bb9b32606dba4471ecc64796010413
Failed to remove container (e3424e6548302125f51ace8b6777190f02bb9b32606dba4471ecc64796010413): Error response from daemon: No such container: e3424e6548302125f51ace8b6777190f02bb9b32606dba4471ecc64796010413
core@www ~/szeremi-nginx $ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
78bb85b82e16        mysql:5.7                     "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          3306/tcp                                   mysql
e2335f1ab0b5        amcsi/szeremi                 "npm run start"          2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:10082->8080/tcp                    szeremi
bd22591d62ae        jwilder/nginx-proxy           "/app/docker-entrypoi"   4 days ago          Up 4 days           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   szeremi-nginx
c36ce4003505        centurylink/watchtower        "/watchtower"            4 days ago          Up 4 days                                                      watchtower
7cedd4eb3d6c        sameersbn/redmine:3.2.0-2     "/sbin/entrypoint.sh "   4 weeks ago         Up 4 days           443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10083->80/tcp             dockerredmine_redmine_1
9305e9e6b3a2        sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-11   "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"    4 weeks ago         Up 4 days           5432/tcp                                   dockerredmine_postgresql_1
e00edc4f605e        holmes/dockerpuller           "--help"                 8 weeks ago         Created                                                        loving_bartik
core@www ~/szeremi-nginx $ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 8acee1b
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart docker service?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I did restart the entire machine though which fixed the issue.

Comment: So, as a result docker daemon was restarted too... Sorry, I dunno better solution yet.